# Select multiple cells in a row and find their sum jquery - kendo ui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, sum, grid, cell

I need to get the selected values of multiple cells in a row and find their sum using kendo grid ui jquery.

Is it possible to  select multiple columns and find the **sum on each row and display the result as another column**.[selected column and result format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22nfa.png)

Comment: How do you want to select the row/cells ? What you have tried ?

Comment: Hi, I need to select the columns and find the sum of each row and display the result as another column.

Comment: David's answer already shows you how to do it.

Comment: From the given example we are able to calculate the total sum of all the selected rows. But  if I select 2 columns and 3 rows I need to find the sum of each row separately and display the result in a different column.

Comment: Why won't you tell David about that so he can improve his answer ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `selectable.mode` property to `multiple, cell`.
2. In the `change` event, get the selected cells by calling `this.select()`
3. Get just the values of the selected cells by calling `Object.values`
4. Filter the values to only return values that are `<td />` elements
5. Map the filtered values to only return the converted inner text of the element
6. Reduce the filtered and mapped values by adding the values together

Example:

```js
change: function() {
  var selectedCells = Object.values(this.select())
    .filter(function(value) {
      return value && value.nodeName && value.nodeName == 'TD';
    })
    .map(function(td) {
      return Number(td.innerText);
    });
  var total = selectedCells.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  console.log(total);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/oNUJaxiG

**Update**

After some discussion in the question comments, the OP made it clear that they need the sum of each individual row with selected cells. In this case, the `change` method will need to modified slightly to essentially group by the row:

```js
change: function() {
  var selectedCells = Object.values(this.select())
    .filter(function(value) {
      return value && value.nodeName && value.nodeName == 'TD';
    });
  var selectedRows = {};
  $.each(selectedCells, function(index, cell) {
    var parent = cell.parentNode.getAttribute('data-uid');
    if (Object.keys(selectedRows).indexOf(parent) < 0) {
      selectedRows[parent] = [];
    }
    selectedRows[parent].push(Number(cell.innerText));
  });
  $.each(Object.keys(selectedRows), function(index, key) {
    var row = selectedRows[key];
    var total = row.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
    console.log(`Row ${key} total: ${total}`);
  });
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/unOTesaD

Comment: Check out the question comments.